# Problem with color background

Tags: tables, color

This has grey background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}  
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{230.0, 230.0, 230.0}
\pagecolor{myblue}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

fsgdf

\end{document}
```

This hasn't grey background. Why please?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Segoe UI Symbol}  
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{230.0, 230.0, 230.0}
\pagecolor{myblue}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption[]{E}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cr}
\hline\hline\noalign{\smallskip}
A&A \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I only replace text by table

Comment: If there is some text on the same page, there's no problem. Other than that, you can write `\begin{table}[!h...]` or `\leavevmode\begin{table}`.

Comment: Thank you and is it possible to write ř in this font? \v{r} does not work and ř as well even when I set czech balbel

Comment: `ř`? Yes. Directly if you have it on your keyboard or via `\v r`. Latin Modern is the default font for `fontspec`.

Comment: And is it possible in Segoe UI Symbol in some way?

Comment: No, this font has only `š` and `ž`. But you can have it  with `Segoe UI`.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98103/discussion-between-lukas-altman-and-bernard).